# Swift: Key has no data exception, despite checking for nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm scratching my head over this one, I thought the whole point of checking for nil was to ensure unsafe variables were ignored at run-time allowing the app to not crash.

I have tried to check the key returned from the server for nil, and also tried optional chaining to test for nil, neither are working and I still get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "avatar" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'
```

I understand this means that no data was found for the avatar key, but due to the tests I am running I'm confused why this error is even being raised

```
for var i = 0; i < recipients.count; i++
{
    if let u = recipients[i] as PFUser!
    {
        if u.valueForKey("avatar") != nil
        {
            println(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Conversely, I tried to optional chain the result of the image:

```
if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: (u["avatar"]!.getData() as NSData?)!) {}
```

Both times the application will crash throwing the exception stated above. My stack trace shows nothing else which is of use, however the println statement will print 0, 1 and then crash on element 2 (where the collection size is 4 so I am not out of bounds).

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: hmm, it may sound strange, but my answer is: don't use the parse framework. it creates more problems than it solves.. just my 2 cents.

Comment: I completely agree Michael I won't be using it again.  I used it as it was required for further learning as part of my degree, I would rather write my own api for future projects

Comment: you can tell your teacher that using parse was just too easy, and that you are ambituous (and want a good grade) and want to learn much, so you decided to write your own backend - even though you already started with "parse".. (btw. don't use AFNetworking neither, just use NSURLConnection, it knows how to make HTTP requests sufficiently well.)

Comment: Unfortunately the due date is in two days so gonna stick with parse for now. But you're right it's been far too easy and hasn't made me any more productive. I'm just far too comfortable with back end architecture, oh well we all learn from our mistakes.  Thanks for the advice too, this was my first ios project so it's good to know best practices for future reference :)

Comment: yeah, I would like to help you more, but debugging parse bugs had been a pain for me in the past. if you need a quick (awful) workaround, just use try/catch exception handling ;)

Comment: Think ill do that for now, isn't best practice but at least it will work :p thanks again for your help :)